# Getting Angular: error with latest version

Tags: angular5

I want to migrate my app angular4 to angular5, but it's looks ng version have some issue with latest version.

Any Idea what is the stable version for angular5. @angular/cli.

Step I followed:
Installed latest version of node 8.9.1
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

```
ng -v

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 8.9.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: error
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router


typescript: error
webpack: error
```

Comment: needs more info to help.

Comment: I want to try angular5 before I migrate my ng4 app. So I started with fresh installation with node and npm. Do I need to user any specific version instead of @latest in this command for ng5 npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: The latest version of Angular5 is [5.1.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#510-2017-12-06)

Comment: I tried step as per https://cli.angular.io/ it's installed and showing Angular CLI version: 1.6.0. But still typescript: error
webpack: error show when I do ng -v. I am not sure what will be the impact if I generate my prod build with this version.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of typescript also? Check this. http://onlyforcoder.blogspot.in/2017/11/angular-5-upgrade-your-project-To-Angular5.html

Comment: it's work after install npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact ... Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

> it's work after install npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact ...
>   Thanks.! – Umang Savaliya Dec 7 '17 at 9:34

Solved in their comments by checking the dependencies are up to date.

`npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact` with `Angular` 5.1 with `Angular-CLI v1.6.0`

Resolve this issue.